# Return records repeated according to field value

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a table like this

```
Name         Qty   
-----        -----
BD             2
SD             1
XE             3
```

I need to return this table records repeated according to the field `Qty` value. for example first row would be repeated twice with all same values.

I was thinking to use nested `FOR Select` inside stored procedure with return parameters

```
For Select name, qty from mytable into :name, :qty do
  begin
    if (qty > 1 ) then begin
      i = 1; -- should I start from 2 ?
      while (i <= :qty) do
      begin

        for select name, qty from mytable into :name1, :qty1 do ...

        SUSPEND;

        i = i + 1;
      end


    end

    SUSPEND;
end
```

Can this stored procedure return the correct result or should I use another way ?

I use FireBird 2.5 and please discard any typos in the previous SQL I am looking only to main idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [recursive CTE](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-select.html#langrefupd25-select-cte), supported since version 2.1, something like

```
WITH RECURSIVE tQty AS(
    SELECT ta.name, ta.qty
       FROM T ta
       WHERE(ta.qty > 0)
 UNION ALL
    SELECT tb.name, tb.qty-1
       FROM tQty tb
       WHERE(tb.qty-1 > 0)
 )
 SELECT name,qty FROM tQty
       ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Looks interesting, although if I understand it right you need the `anchor` (first subselect) and one `subselect` for each level of recursion. I tried your select with the OP's example and it repeated the `XE` value only 2 times. When I added another subselect it repeated that value 3 times. Do you know if there is any way to do it without having to add a subselect for each level?

Comment: Hmm, I tested it with FB2.5 and got expected result.

Comment: I have a record where `Qty = 4` but repeated 2 times only. can you modify ?

Comment: @ain, nevermind, I had a typo in my query. Instead of `tQty` in the second subselect I had written `T`.

Comment: @Wel, I think you have a similar typo in your query like Guillem had - make sure you replace the table name `T` with the real one only on the first SELECT, others must select from `tQty`.

Comment: @ain Yes, It work now and very fast. Would you please explain how the subtracting work in `tb.qty-1` ?

Comment: The `(tb.qty-1 > 0)` is the condition which stops the recursion. The "top level call" is SELECT from the original table with the original qty field value which is passed to the recursive part of the query (tQty). In the recursive part one is subtracted from the Qty value and if it is still > 0 then row is outputted and next level of recursion is called with current qty value.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Numbers table, this is trivial:

```
SELECT
    OT.Name
FROM
    OrigTable AS OT
    INNER JOIN Numbers AS N ON N.Number BETWEEN 1 AND OT.Qty
```

I'm not familiar with Firebird, but I trust this very simple syntax applies.